# Custom struct types in memory

Tags: c#, struct

I know that `class` types or reference types has a reference in stack memory, and value types, if defined as local variables, reside in stack as well. However, I know how `int`, `double`, etc. types reside in stack but not quite sure how custom struct types are being located in stack. For instance:

```
public struct Employee
{
   public int Age {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
}

static void Main(params string[] args)
{
   Employee employee; // How does it look like in stack at the moment of declaration?
   employee = new Employee(); // And during this line?
   employee.Name = "Hello World"; // And during this statement?
}
```

Can you explain how `employee` struct reside in memory? I can imagine that `Age` and `Name` are located like other variables but how `Employee` encapsulates them in stack? A nice detailed explanation would be really nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All value types (i.e. struct) are stored in the stack *only* when they are a local variable or a by-value parameter (i.e. the usual kind of parameter). This includes int, bool, etc. and custom structs. Answering "how" this happens is simply a matter of knowing how memory storage works generally, but the basic idea is that it works exactly the same as for reference types, except that the computer uses the area of memory called "the stack" instead of the area of memory called "the heap". The main difference between those two areas is simply how use of the areas is managed. Otherwise, they are both just places in computer memory and work the same (i.e. a pointer into one works the same as a pointer into the other).

For more information about reference types vs value types, and especially why you should not really care about where value types are being stored (especially since when part of a reference type, they are still stored in the heap), see this well-known article from Eric Lippert:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail.aspx

Comment: Sounds fair. But still I would like to learn how stuck is placed in  the stack. I don't want to specific detail how class is placed but I know that there is a reference in stack that points at the object in the heap. I want to know how this part works for struct.

Comment: A variable is simply a way of describing some location in memory to the compiler. When dealing with a local or by-value parameter: In the case of a reference type the variable itself still refers to a place in the stack, where that place stores a pointer to the actual data in the heap. Since it's a reference type, the compiler knows to "dereference" the pointer to get to the actual data location in the heap. When you have a variable that is a value type variable instead, it still describes a location in the stack, it's just that the data's right there instead of needing the dereference.

Comment: And please be careful: all of the above is specifically for local variables and by-value parameters, and only in C# (and similar languages) today. Just as the article I linked to explains, this is an implementation detail, the details are different when the variable is not a local or by-value parameter, and there's no fundamental reason that even in those cases it _has_ to be implemented this way (it's just that it fits with the normal computer architectures).

Comment: Thanks for the shout-out. This article is also relevant: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types.aspx

Comment: @EricLippert: yes, that's a great article too!

Answer (score 2):

In normal situation you should not be worried how the the struct is laid out in memory. CLR decides it on it's own. If you need a particular layout you can control it with StructLayout attribute.

The new keyword in your case just provides the same semantics which you use when newing up a class object on heap.

```
Employee employee;
employee = new Employee();
```

is equal to writing:

```
var employee = new Employee();
```

Actually, if you do not use the new operator, it will be reported on the next line:

> .. Use of unassigned local variable `employee`.

Assignment of a struct variable copies of all the fields of source struct, but that is not the case, because it's just an initialization expression, and there's no reason to copy anything yet.
Constructor just acts upon the fields of the new object residing in stack along with it's field values, pretty much as if you declared a set of similar local variables. In this case, it's just intitializing the fileds with default values: zero for an int, and null for a string.

And in this statement:

```
employee.Name = "Hello World";
```

It does a call to a setter function, which in turn assigns the value to a private field. This setter function would be inlined if compiled with optimizations.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, you almost never need to worry about how the stack is actually laid out in memory, or for that matter, whether a stack is used at all. Remember, registers are often also used to implement temporary storage.

The way that the jitter lays out a record on the stack is implementation-dependent and can vary from machine to machine. To find out how your program lays out in memory on your machine: compile it, debug it, go into assembly level debugging, and examine the memory around the stack register. Watch how that memory changes as you step from statement to statement and pretty soon you'll figure it out.

Comment: I liked the suggestion to make assembly level debugging.